# bubbleで作ったアプリに自作のコードを組み合わせるやり方がわからない

Tags: プログラミング言語

bubbleで作ったアプリに自作のコードを組み合わせたいです。今はまだ何もコードを書いていない状態で、わからないところが2つあります。

1.bubbleに使用するためのプログラミング言語がPythonでないとだめなど、bubbleで作ったアプリに組み合わせるために使用する自作のコードのプログラミング言語に規定があるのか。

2.bubbleで作ったアプリのコードをコピーしてローカル環境で自作のコードを書き込むために、bubbleで作ったアプリのコードをどこからどうやってコピーすればよいのか。

Comment: bubble というのは https://bubble.io/ のことであっていますでしょうか。

Comment: この辺のサイト [トップ > Bubble - ノーコード ラボ](https://blog.nocodelab.jp/archive/category/Bubble), [HOME/エンジニアブログ/Bubble - THE SIMPLE](https://the-simple.jp/category/engineer/bubble) に大量の記事があるようです。この中を探すか、直接質問してみてはどうでしょう？

Answer (score 0):

部分回答になりますが、 Bubble 上で作成したアプリのデータをエクスポートすることは出来ないようです。

あくまで Bubble 上での実行のみを想定しているので、別のプログラミング言語と連携してということも仕組み上難しそうです。

[Exporting your application & data](https://manual.bubble.io/new-start-here/application-and-data-ownership)

> Bubble apps can only be run on the Bubble platform; there's no way of exporting your application as code.